# Regex is matching in Javascript but not PCRE

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all fractions or 'evs' and strings (string1, string2) the following string with regex. **The strings may contain any number of white spaces ('String 1', 'The String 1', 'The String Number 1').**

```
10/3 string1 evs string2 8/5 mon 19:45 string1 v string2 1/1 string1 v string2 1/1
```

The following regex works in Javascript but not in PHP. No errors are returned, just 0 results.

```
(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs).*?(.+).*?(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs).*?(.+).*?(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs).*?(.+) v (.+).*?(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs).*?(.+) v (.+).*?(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)
```

Here's the expected result, other than group 6 and 7 (ran using Javascript):

[image]

If I add a `?` to the first `(.+)` so that it becomes `(.+?)`, I get the desired result but with the first string not captured:

[image]

As soon as I remove the `?` to capture the whole string, there are no results returned. Can somebody work out what's going on here?

Comment: You should avoid `+?` and `*?`. Can you explain what you would like to achieve, we may think of an improved pattern?

Comment: what are you trying to capture?

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek Sure. I'm aiming to capture the fractions and the strings (string1 and string2), ignoring everything else. The regex string needs to be able to be built up dynamically by the columns that are defined in a prior function (each column has the regex for the element in that column e.g. a fraction is (\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)).

Comment: Does `(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)` not give you the expected matches?

Comment: Can you provide the correct expected result? I'm still not sure if you want to match `evs`, `string1` etc.,

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek Sure, I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure that you expect to get `mon 1` and then `9`?

Comment: Let's admit: this pattern does not work well anywhere, just look at `.*?(.+).*?`. Backtracking steps are killing. This is plain catastrophic backtracking. You can't build a pattern like this and you need to completely re-write it.

Comment: Without more details, I suggest replacing almost all `.*?` with `\s+` and `.+` with `\S+`: `(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(.+?)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(\S+)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)`

Comment: Or, the same can be written as `(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(.+?)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(\S+)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))` in PCRE. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQMF3u/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for this, it seems to match as expected. In a large string of multiple instances of this pattern is only matching once though. How would I make this match all instances of the pattern?

Comment: What is your programming language? PHP? Use `preg_match_all`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Never mind, I needed to add the `global` flag. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You do not need `g` flag in PHP

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, got it, thanks. How would I capture `string 1` instead of `string1`?

Comment: @AlexGodbehere I am writing an answer, I have already written that you need to use *precise* patterns. I do not know your log format, you know it, so if you are sure there is a word and then a number, you may use `[a-zA-Z]+ \d+` to get that bit.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/NQMF3u/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCRE/PHP, you may use

```
$regex = '(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(.+?)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+(\S+)\s+v\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQMF3u/2)

The point is that you can't over-use `.*?` / `.+` in the middle of the pattern, that leads to catastrophic backtracking.

You need to use precise patterns to match whitespace, and non-whitespace fields, and only use `.*?` / `.+?` where the fields can contain any amount of whitespace and non-whitespace chars.

**Details**

- `(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)` - Group 1 (its pattern can be later accessed using `(?1)` subroutine): one to three digits, `/` and then one to three digits, or `evs`
- `\s+(\S+)\s+` - 1+ whitespaces, Group 2 matching 1+ non-whitespace chars, 1+ whitespaces
- `((?1))` - Group 3 that matches the same way Group 1 pattern does
- `\s+(\S+)\s+((?1))\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces, Group 4 matching 1+ non-whitespaces, 1+ whitespaces, Group 5 with the Group 1 pattern, 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)` - Group 6: matching any 1 or more char chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+v\s+` - `v` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 7: 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\s+((?1))\s+` - 1+ whitespaces, Group 8 with Group 1 pattern, 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 9: 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\s+v\s+` - `v` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)\s+((?1))` - Group 10: 1+ non-whitespaces, then 1+ whitespaces and Group 11 with Group 1 pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to add the constraint that the words can contain any number of whitespace.

Comment: @AlexGodbehere The answer is still the same. I do not know your log format. You must use **precise patterns for each field**.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using `.+`. `(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs) (.+) (\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs) ((?2)) (\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs) ((?2)) v ((?2)) (\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs) ((?2)) v ((?2)) (\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}|evs)`